# Python opencv having trouble cropping frames from a video

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

## Description

I'm pretty new to Python and opencv, and I would like to use opencv to crop frames from a video. The work flow is as follows: I opened up an image and get some coordinate values from mousecallback function. Since the video was taken with a cell-phone on a tripod, I would expect the region of interest should be fixed in space. Therefore, I can use the coordinate to batch process other frames. The first cropped image is done and saved as expected but I have a problem processing the other frames.

## Code

### imported packages

```py
import cv2
```

### mouse call back

```py
def get_retval(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        ix, iy = x, y
```

### get coord

```py
def get_cropped():
    while True:
        count = 1
        while count < 4:
            cv2.imshow('get reference', img)
            k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
            if k == 27:
                break
            elif k == ord('a'):
                if count == 1:
                    # upperleft
                    x1, y1 = ix, iy
                elif count == 2:
                    # upperright
                    x2, _ = ix, iy
                    # bottom
                elif count == 3:
                    _, y2 = ix, iy
                count += 1
        cropped_img = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        cv2.imshow("cropped", cropped_img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        if k == ord('g'):
            cv2.imwrite(data_out + "frame_0.png", cropped_img)
            return [x1, y1, x2, y2]
            cv2.destroyWindow("cropped")
            break
        else:
            cv2.destroyWindow("cropped")
```

Whenever there is a double clicks on the left button, the coord will be recorded, and I pressed 'a' key to record assign the value to $x_i$ and $y_i$ for i = 1 and 2. Then, it gives me a preview of the cropped image. If the image looks good, the script returns the coord.

### main function

```py
try:
    base_dir = 'xxx'
    vid_dir = base_dir + 'yyy'
    processing_vid = 'zzz'
    data_out = '/Data/Work/'
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_dir + processing_vid)

    frame_count = 0
    while vidcap.isOpened() is True:
        retval, image = vidcap.read()
        totalFrames = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        if retval is True and frame_count == 0:
            cv2.imwrite('/tmp/ref.png', image)
            img = cv2.imread('/tmp/ref.png')
            cv2.namedWindow('get reference')
            img = cv2.resize(img, (960, 540))
            cv2.setMouseCallback('get reference', get_retval)
            x1, x2, y1, y2 = get_cropped()

        if retval is True and frame_count != 0:
            cv2.namedWindow('test cropping')
            image = cv2.resize(image, (960, 540))
            cropped = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
            cv2.imshow('test cropping', cropped) 
        if frame_count == 10:
            break
        frame_count += 1


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I use the very first frame as a reference to get the coord. This works pretty good. Then, for the other frame, I resize them to the same size as the reference frame and crop them the same way as I did in the function `get_cropped`. However, it just gives me an error

## Error msg from terminal

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Data/Dropbox/coding/functions/imageProcessing/June11.py", line 71, in 
cv2.imshow('test cropping', cropped)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.2/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:412: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

## Debugging

I tried to print out the image without cropping and it looks normal. However, once I cropped it, it returns an empty array [].

Could anyone help me find out what I did wrong? Sorry for my long description! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: message `size.width>0 && size.height>0` can means you have empty array. Maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables, Maybe you have wrong coordinates and it can't crop it. Or you have them in wrong order - it may need `x1 < x2`, `y1 < y2`

Comment: @furas Yeah, I printed out the image and it looks like a normal numpy array. And, as you mentioned, once I cropped the image, it just outputs an empty array. I think the x_i and y_i are in the correct order bc the first frame is cropped as I expected

Comment: error shows problem in line `cv2.imshow('test cropping', ...)` but I don't see this line in your code. Maybe you run different code.

Comment: @furas you're right! I was running a slightly diff code. Please see my updated question. Many thanks!

Comment: I think I see problem - you mess with coordinates. `get_cropped()` returns `return [x1, y1, x2, y2]` but you assign it to `x1, x2, y1, y2 = get_cropped(...)` - so you assign them in wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but I think I see problem - you mess with coordinates.

`get_cropped()` returns

```
return [x1, y1, x2, y2]
```

but you assign it to

```
x1, x2, y1, y2 = get_cropped(...)
```

so you assign them in wrong order - you replace `x2` with `y1`

It should be

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = get_cropped(...)
```

Comment: if this resolves your problem then you can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you may upvote it.